# React native : Is there any way to redirect the initial route to another page

Tags: react-native

I'm new in react native and currently developing a react-native app that require login. After successful login, the view change into Homepage. **The problem is after i close and re-open the app, it shows me LoginPage again**.***Is there any way to redirect the initial route to another page***

```
 class Main extends Component {

  _renderScene(route, navigator) {
      if (route.id === 1) {
        return <LoginPage navigator={navigator} />
      } else if (route.id === 2) {
        return <HomePage navigator={navigator} />
      } else if (route.id === 3) {
        return <DetailPage navigator={navigator} />
      }  else if (route.id === 4) {
        return <CreateBookingPage navigator={navigator} />
      }
  }

  _configureScene(route) {
    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight;
  }


  render() {
      return (
        <Navigator
        initialRoute={{id: 1, }}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
        configureScene={ () => { return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight; }} />
      );
  }
}
```

/////after some changes I get into this but still its rendering the login is I done something wrong////////

```
   componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('key').then( (value) => {
        if(value==="yes") {
            this.setState({ loader: false, logged: true})
        } else {
            this.setState({ loader: false })
        }
    })
}

render() {
    const routeId = this.state.logged ? 2 : 1;
    if(this.state.loader) {
        return (
            <View /> // loading screen
        );
    }
    return (
        <Navigator
            initialRoute={{id: routeId }}
            renderScene={this._renderScene}
            configureScene={ () => { return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight; }} />
    );
}
```

Comment: Set dynamically initialRoute value based on user logged status.

Comment: Do you know how to set dynamically initial route.... can you add sample here

Comment: Based on your requirment, you need to update id value. like initialRoute={{id: (condition ? 1: 2) }}

Comment: can you add example I really dont know how i gonna add this in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On successful login you could set a token/value in the local storage of the device and on logout clear this value. 
You could check this value for setting the initial route. `Asyncstorage` can be used in setting and removing the logged status.

**EDIT:**
Initial state of loader should be true, logged should be false

```
  componentWillMount() { 
   AsyncStorage.getItem('key').then( (value) => {
     if(value) {
       this.setState({ loader: false, logged: true})
     } else {
       this.setState({ loader: false })
    }
   })
 }

  render() {
    const { loader } = this.state;
    const routeId = logged ? 2 : 1;
    if(loader) { 
    return (
     <View /> // loading screen
   );
}
    return (
      <Navigator
      initialRoute={{id: routeId }}
      renderScene={this._renderScene}
      configureScene={ () => { return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight; }} />
    );
 }
```

Comment: is there any way to use the value directly because it takes time and render  function get executes immediately.....

Comment: return in render can be done conditionally , until the value is obtained from AsyncStorage, you could return a loading screen. When the value is obtained you could setState and return navigator with with required initial route

Comment: please add sample example i really dont know what i can do this

Comment: I am really stuck and feeling dumb at this moment I have edited my question please check if i done something wrong

Comment: You need two states, one for whether to show loader or not , second for whether the user is already logged in

Comment: Did you set initial states?

Comment: make sure you are setting value with proper key, using same key to retrieve it. Do bit of debugging(console log state values in render etc). Thats how you learn what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Replace with your render function and try it.

```
  render() {
    var loggedStatus = true; // change here for login screen
    var routeId = loggedStatus ? 2 : 1;
    return (
      <Navigator
      initialRoute={{id: routeId }}
      renderScene={this._renderScene}
      configureScene={ () => { return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight; }} />
    );
 }
```

Comment: But how i can change the status of loggedStatus  variable since my class file for login is in different file I mean after API call i have to change this value

Comment: Once successfully logged, you need to set some cookie value for logged status and get it here.

Comment: how this cookie value can be generated I really dont know

Comment: Go through this article. https://medium.com/@ntoscano/react-native-persistent-user-login-6a48ff380ab8

Comment: Or you can you react-native-cookies modules. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cookies

Comment: Hi Yogeshwar, After successfully login, enter user details in AsyncStorage http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/asyncstorage.html and it will persist value of user data when app close or reopen after few days, from any page, you can check stored user value and redirect to whichever page you want

Comment: is there any way to use the value directly because it takes time and render  function get executes immediately.....although I used componentWillMount function also